# What do we call 'traditional' ASP.NET when trying to reference with respect to ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It cannot be called classic, because that would get confused with classic ASP. I don't like calling it traditional because of the connotation that word has.

Do we called it:
Normal ASP.NET
Mainstream ASP.NET
ASP.NET MVP

What else?

Comment: I might start calling it "Normal ASP.NET Mainstream ASP.NET ASP.NET MVP" just to try and encourage management that it's a platform that we would be better without

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called ASP.Net WebForms.

Comment: Can you provide documentation for this?

Comment: Can you also provide documentation regarding the documentation?

Comment: There's ASP.NET, and on top of that there are Web Forms and MVC. 

@Baddie: http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Comment: Scott Guthrie refers to the two technologies using this terminology.  Considering he heads up that area at Microsoft, I would say he's pretty much the authority:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/24/about-technical-debates-both-in-general-and-regarding-asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-in-particular.aspx

Comment: Forgot to wrap my initial comment with <sarcasm />

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with just "ASP.NET"?  It's "ASP.NET MVC" that is the clarifier.  Do you mean in speech or referring to tags here?

Comment: ASP.NET is the common denominator between ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC.  MVC does not supercede ASP.NET, so MVC *is* ASP.NET just like WebForms *is* ASP.NET